# Silently download ID token

Tags: c#, web-services, oauth, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a requirement that user will provide username and password into one application and that application will call a web service with these user credentials.

The web service will authenticate the user against Azure Active Directory and download ID token and return that to calling application.

Note: calling application only have to pass user-provided credentials and gets back the authentication information from the service.

Comment: This is strange that mods closed this question, may be they can't understand question right, still i got required answer from junnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is use the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow (ROPC).
I have a whole article on why I recommend **you don't use it**: https://joonasw.net/view/ropc-grant-flow-in-azure-ad.

If the user has Multi-Factor Authentication turned on, it won't work.
If their password has expired, it won't work (and they have no way to fix it).

I recommend that you do not use this flow.
Use a more secure, interactive flow such as authorization code flow: [Desktop app calling API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-overview) / [Web app calling API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview).

Handling user passwords is usually an extremely bad idea when you are using an identity provider.